# IOS/Swift: Open PDF from a local path into a Web View

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, webview

I previously used below code to open up a dummy PDF, just for testing purpose, and now for the actual project i have to load a pdf based on the table cell clicked that will give the exact path of the pdf at some local path.

```
self.termsPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("DemoForm", ofType: "pdf")!
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: termsPath!)
let pdfRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
pdfWebView.loadRequest(pdfRequest)
pdfWebView.scalesPageToFit = true
```

Now i have thisvariable **docPath** that will be passed from the prepareforSegue when table cell is clicked, i tried to use this variable in place of DemoForm but it gives below error

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0

Where i'm i going wrong here? Can anyone help me.Thanks

EDIT: By the way my docPath refers to something like **".../.../.../.../Referral.pdf"**

Comment: Why are you unwrapping termsPath twice? BTW You should use URLForResource(:withExtension) for local resources

Comment: i tried using URLForResource(self.docPath, withExtension: "pdf") it says missing argument for subdirectory, which then i added, and it says extra argument subdirectory. I think swift has mind of it's own, So i'm i doing something wrong here?

Comment: . URLForResource("DemoForm", withExtension: "pdf") to get the NSURL

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, i was trying to load pdf from a local path as in **Users/someName/Documents/something/.../../../.../.../Referral.pdf** Which is quite different from where DemoForm is stored. I used NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomain to get the local path. Everything works fine until here, now when i'm trying to load the pdf into webView it gives me an exception saying, **failed to find PDF header: `%PDF` not found** . You know anything about this? Thanks

Comment: Figured it out. It's one of my dumb mistakes again, I've dragged and dropped the pdf files on to a folder, by which instead copying those files it created short cuts. Thanks for help @leonardo

Comment: You are welcome try obtaining the url for your pdf file using the method I mentioned. No need to use fileUrlWithPath